# Rails Finding towns within a 10 mile radius of postcode. Google maps API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-geocoder

I'm using the [geocoder gem](http://www.rubygeocoder.com/) and was wondering if there is a way to get all cities within a radius (with center coordinates).

Something like

```
city = location.cities(100) #all cities within 100km
```

There seems to be a [PHP solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8135243/finding-towns-within-a-10-mile-radius-of-postcode-google-maps-api), but I'm not sure how it can be used in my case.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe GoogleMap API offers spatial search. [Geonames.org](http://www.geonames.org/export/web-services.html) site publishes such a Web service -- the associated [Geonames gem](http://www.tbcn.ca/ruby_geonames) doc has a specific example for finding places near a lat/long point:

```
places_nearby = Geonames::WebService.find_nearby_place_name 43.900120387, -78.882869834
```