# How to get cities near my

Tags: javascript, php

I want to get all cities close to my actual geolocalisation (by GPS) in a X radius. A good example is the app Tinder. The user select the value of radius in KM and the app gets all the cities close to his geolocalisation inside the selected radius.

I want to calculate the radius and get all cities within by **javascript or PHP**.

An illustration:

[image]

Comment: The app tinder likely uses some sort of geospatial database to calculate stuff like that. Without it you would need a lat/long for every target city and likely loop over every one to get a "great sphere distance" and see if within the target range. The geospatial database indexes all this stuff and it then becomes a simple query. There might be some sort of google API also to handle spatial queries.

Comment: take a look at this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8135243/finding-towns-within-a-10-mile-radius-of-postcode-google-maps-api](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8135243/finding-towns-within-a-10-mile-radius-of-postcode-google-maps-api)

Answer (score 1):

You can download a database of all US cities, with their states and latitude/longitude, then query the database based on current GPS info.  Just google search for a DB, they are about 30 meg, so make sure your queries are optimized.

Here is a db that should work...
https://www.maxmind.com/en/free-world-cities-database

If you can find a geospacial database it would perform better (not sure if linked one is or not).  I have used a non geospacial one and it was fine though.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply me.
Ok, once I have the DB with all cities and latitude/longitude, how should I calculate de radius in KM to get all cities close to me inside this radius selected?

Comment: Pythagorean theorem sqrt(abs(lat1 - lat2)^2 + abs(long1 - long2)^2);
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Comment: It helped me. But my really problem is: how does I calculate the radius around my actual latitude and longitude to get all the cities around me? Then I can make the query. But how can I calculate it?